# create favourite button using toogleButton

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick, android-togglebutton, oncheckedchanged

i'm trying to add a favourite button using toogleButton that displays a certain icon when unchecked and another icon when checked. I tried this but isn't working.
Here is the toggleButton

```
<ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fav_fragment_title"
            android:id="@+id/favButton"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
```

and this is my recycler adapter.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;
    private Context context;




    public List<CardItemModel> cardItems;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<CardItemModel> cardItems){
        this.cardItems = cardItems;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView copyButton;
        ImageView shareButton;
        ToggleButton favButton;


        TextView title;
        TextView content;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            this.content = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_content);
            this.copyButton= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.copyButton);
            this.shareButton=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
            this.favButton=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favButton);
            favButton.setChecked(false);
            favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));


        }
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(cardItems.get(position).title);
        holder.content.setText(cardItems.get(position).content);
        holder.copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){


                myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", holder.content.getText().toString());
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }
        });
        holder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, holder.content.getText().toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
            }
        });

        holder.favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                if (isChecked)
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                else
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_cart));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardItems.size();
    }
}
```

Also how can I add the favourited recyclerView to another fragment?

Comment: Please tell us what exactly the problem is. What you mean by "it is not working"?

Answer (score 4):

Add a Drawable selector and use it as Background in `ToggleButton`

```
<ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fav_fragment_title"
        android:id="@+id/favButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_image"
        />
```

in `res/drawable/toggle_image.xml`:

Add your select/unselect images

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Comment: thanks it helped. now can you please give some idea how can I add the favourited recyclerView to another fragment?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496177/values-from-recyclerview-item-to-other-activity  pass your favourited item data as bundle to other activity